# Laravel / Eloquent - How Do You Run Multiple Raw SQL Statements At the Same Time?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have multiple SQL statements I'd like to run through Eloquent.  They look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cars
    AS (SELECT cars.id, cars.ip_address
        FROM cars
            JOIN colors ON colors.ip_address = cars.ip_address);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE boats
    AS (SELECT ip_address, MIN(id) AS id
        FROM colors
        GROUP BY ip_address);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE rvs
    AS (SELECT rvs.id, rvs.ip_address
        FROM rvs
            LEFT JOIN colors ON colors.id = rvs.id
        WHERE colors.id IS NULL);

/* Do things with temp tables here */
```

I need all of these statements to run in one connection session since they are using temporary tables.  I've tried using `DB::statement()` which errors out at the start of the second statement operation and also `DB::unprepared()` which doesn't seem to run any of the operations.

Is there a way to run multiple raw statements using Eloquent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with the `unprepared` statement, but I feel like it's possible that utilizing a transaction may be advantageous in your scenario. Furthermore, you'll want to use `\DB::raw()` which will execute your SQL statement as a flat string. Of course, do not put anything in here that could be user provided as you'd open yourself up to SQL injection given that you're bypassing parameterized queries.

```
try {
    \DB::transaction(function(){
        \DB::unprepared(\DB::raw('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cars AS (SELECT cars.id, cars.ip_address FROM cars JOIN colors ON colors.ip_address = cars.ip_address)'));

        \DB::unprepared(\DB::raw('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE boats AS (SELECT ip_address, MIN(id) AS id FROM colors GROUP BY ip_address)'));

        \DB::unprepared(\DB::raw('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE rvs AS (SELECT rvs.id, rvs.ip_address FROM rvs LEFT JOIN colors ON colors.id = rvs.id WHERE colors.id IS NULL)'));
    });

    \DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e){ 
    \DB::rollback();
    //do something with $e->getMessage();
}
```

Furthermore, this is actually Laravel's `Query Builder` and not `Eloquent`.

Answer (score -2):

You should use laravel customize query. See this [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database) for details

```
$query = DB::select("       
            SELECT
                            cars.id,
                            cars.ip_address,
                        FROM cars
                        JOIN colors
                        ON colors.ip_address = cars.ip_address
                        UNION
                        SELECT
                            ip_address,
                            MIN(id) AS id,
                        FROM colors
                        GROUP BY ip_address
            UNION
                        SELECT
                            rvs.id,
                            rvs.ip_address,
                        FROM rvs
            LEFT JOIN colors 
                        ON colors.id = rvs.id
                        WHERE colors.id IS NULL
               ");
```